# How to factorize $x^2y^2+a(x^2y+xy^2)+b(x^2+y^2)+cxy+d(x+y)+e$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, quadratic-forms

What is the condition on complex constants $a,b,c,d,e$ that allows us to factorize $$x^2y^2+a(x^2y+xy^2)+b(x^2+y^2)+cxy+d(x+y)+e$$ in to linear, quadratic or cubic factors?

Comment: Given the symmetry in $x,y$ let $s=x+y, p=xy$. The only linear factors could be of the form $s+\alpha\,$, and the only quadratic factors $p + \alpha s^2 + \beta s + \gamma\,$, which should give some conditions by identifying the undetermined coefficients. That said, I don't know that they'd be too pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One possibility:**

$\displaystyle \qquad \,
\left[
  xy+
  \frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2} (x+y)-
  b+\frac{c}{2}+
  \frac{ac-2ab-2d}{2\sqrt{a^2-4b}}
\right] \\
\quad \times \displaystyle
\left[
  xy+
  \frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2} (x+y)-
  b+\frac{c}{2}-
  \frac{ac-2ab-2d}{2\sqrt{a^2-4b}}
\right] \\
\displaystyle =
x^2y^2+axy(x+y)+b(x^2+y^2)+cxy+d(x+y)-\frac{b(2b-c)^2+ad(2b-c)+d^2}{a^2-4b}$

> $$e=-\frac{b(2b-c)^2+ad(2b-c)+d^2}{a^2-4b}$$

In particular $b=\dfrac{a^2}{4}$,

$\displaystyle \qquad \,
\left[
  xy+
  \frac{a(x+y)}{2}+
  \frac{c}{2}-\frac{a^2}{4}+
  \sqrt{\left( \frac{c}{2}-\frac{a^2}{4} \right)^2-e} \;
\right] \\
\quad \times \displaystyle
\left[
  xy+
  \frac{a(x+y)}{2}+
  \frac{c}{2}-\frac{a^2}{4}-
  \sqrt{\left( \frac{c}{2}-\frac{a^2}{4} \right)^2-e} \;
\right] \\
\displaystyle =
x^2y^2+axy(x+y)+\frac{a^2(x^2+y^2)}{4}+
cxy+
\left(
  \frac{ac}{2}-\frac{a^3}{4}
\right)(x+y)+e$

> $$d=\frac{ac}{2}-\frac{a^3}{4}$$